# working fine on bootstrap but not on my visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My code just works fine in bootstrap studio but when transferred the same exact code on visual studio 2015, it doesn't read the latitude and longitude being input. it suppose to geocode to a specific place. what else could be  wrong? it says no error in console/f12. ps: i use firefox and IE edge but both of them aren't working fine.

This is my script file:

```
function myMap() {

            //var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.6259431, 121.0058965);
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.6259431, 121.0058965);

            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
            var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 17 };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            document.getElementById('geocode').addEventListener('click', function () {
                geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter
                , draggable: true
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }


        function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
            var input = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
            var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
            var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };
            geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        map.setZoom(17);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map,
                            draggable: true
                        });

                        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    } else {
                        window.alert('No results found');
                    }
                } else {
                    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `myMap()` anywhere?

Comment: no i am just using it to store the "googleMap" does it affect the other function?